# Computing total Gaussian curvature of $ z^2 = - (x^2 + y^2 -16)((x-2)^2 + y^2 -1) ((x+2)^2 + y^2 -1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to compute the total Gaussian curvature of $
  z^2 = - (x^2 + y^2 -16)((x-2)^2 + y^2 -1) ((x+2)^2 + y^2 -1)$ 
in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The first thing that comes in my mind is Gauss--Bonnet theorem. That is for a compact, simply connected space we have $\int_M K dA = 2 \pi \chi(M)$.

But I have no idea how to deal with this surface. For example, I can not image the shape of this surface.

My first trial is $X(u,v) = (u,v, \sqrt{-(u^2 + v^2 -16)((u-2)^2 + v^2 -1) ((u+2)^2 + v^2 -1)})$ and compute total Gaussian curvature. But I am not sure of the last coordinate. My domain was $(u,v) \in [-\infty, \infty] \times [-\infty, \infty]$, and after trial with mathematica the results was terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a topology question.
Let's consider the function:
$$
f(x,y) = - (x^2 + y^2 -16)\times\Big[(x-2)^2 + y^2 -1\Big]\times\Big[(x+2)^2 + y^2 -1\Big]
$$

The manifold $\partial\mathcal R: f(x,y) = 0$ consists of 3 non-intersecting circles. Moreover, $\mathcal R: f(x,y) > 0$ is a [connected region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-16%29%28%28x-2%29%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-1%29%28%28x%2B2%29%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-1%29+%3E+0):

[image]

When we consider, manifold $\Omega: z^2 = f(x,y)$ it basically inflates the region $\mathcal R$, keeping the boundary $\partial\mathcal R$ in place. (You can imagine the process of inflating the disk $x^2+y^2-1<0$ to the sphere $z^2=1-x^2-y^2$):

[image]

You don't need to plot this manifold in 3D to understand that it's homeomorhic to sphere with 2 handles. Can you use Gauss–Bonnet theorem now?

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Now I can apply for the other similar problems as well!   From $\int K dA = 2 \pi \chi(M) = 2 \pi (2-2g) $ I can obtain the answer.